# MySQL if not exists by two columns update other

Tags: mysql, sql-update, where-clause, not-exists

I want to insert record if it not exists by 2 columns, and if exists update column 3, here's the query:

```
INSERT INTO aktai_islaidos_id (akto_id, islaidos_id, savikaina)
       SELECT * FROM (SELECT ? as a, ? as b, ? as c) AS tmp
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT akto_id, islaidos_id, savikaina FROM aktai_islaidos_id 
             WHERE akto_id = a AND islaidos_id = b
       ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE savikaina = VALUES(c);
```

Now I'm getting error what c not exists in fields list, I understand why, but I didn't know how to complete this query correctly and didn't find any examples like what only where selects duplicate all columns, thanks!

EDIT:
Figured out this with stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update(
       IN akt_id INT,
       IN isl_id INT,
       IN sav INT)
BEGIN
       IF (SELECT count(*) FROM aktai_islaidos_id WHERE akto_id = akt_id AND islaidos_id = isl_id) > 0 THEN
            BEGIN
                 UPDATE aktai_islaidos_id SET savikaina = sav WHERE akto_id = akt_id AND islaidos_id = isl_id;
            END;
       ELSE
            BEGIN
                 INSERT INTO aktai_islaidos_id (akto_id, islaidos_id, savikaina) VALUES (akt_id, isl_id, sav);
            END;
       END IF;
END
```